# How to get value of xml element by using xml tags in HierarchicalStreamReader converter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, xstream

I am trying to parse XML into Java objects using spring batch and I'm using HierarchicalStreamReader as a converter to parse and convert objects values from XML tags to my POJO fields. However, while converting, I have to use moveup() and moveDown() method to parse the data which I suppose is not a good practice to follow because if fields positions are changed in XML tags then it will cause a code re-write. I have already tried getAttribute(String name) method to achieve more control for the parameter I'm trying to fetch by using its tag name but it's giving me the error I'm unable to fix.

Also, there's not enough documentation provided for the interface. Please help me to get through this or suggest me some approach for a controlled converter. Thanks in advance...

**Student.xml**

```
<students>
    <student>
        <name>Tony Tester</name>
        <rollNo>1</rollNo>
        <enrollmentDate>2016-10-31</enrollmentDate>
        <sampleTimeStamp>2016-11-07T05:50:45</sampleTimeStamp>
        <salary>16.57</salary>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Nick Newbie</name>
        <rollNo>2</rollNo>
        <enrollmentDate>2017-10-31</enrollmentDate>
        <sampleTimeStamp>2016-11-07T05:50:45</sampleTimeStamp>
        <salary>29.68</salary>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Ian Intermediate</name>
        <rollNo>3</rollNo>
        <enrollmentDate>2018-10-31</enrollmentDate>
        <sampleTimeStamp>2016-11-07T05:50:45</sampleTimeStamp>
        <salary>789.62</salary>
    </student>
</students>
```

**StudentDTO.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="student")
public class StudentDTO 
{
    private String name;
    private Integer rollNo;    
    private Date enrollmentDate;
    private Date sampleTimeStamp;
    private BigDecimal salary;
    ... getter, setter and constructor
}
```

**StudentConverter.java**

```
public class StudentConverter implements Converter
{

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class type) 
    {
        return type.equals(StudentDTO.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) 
    {
        // Nothing to marshal
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) 
    {
        //reader.getAttribute(0) -- line causing error
                //reader.getAttribute("name") -- return null
                //reader.getAttributeCount() -- always return 0
        reader.moveDown();      
        StudentDTO student = new StudentDTO();
        student.setName(reader.getValue());

        reader.moveUp();
        reader.moveDown();
        student.setRollNo(Integer.parseInt(reader.getValue()));

        reader.moveUp();
        reader.moveDown();
        try 
        {
            student.setEnrollmentDate(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(reader.getValue()));
        } 
        catch (ParseException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        reader.moveUp();
        reader.moveDown();
        try 
        {
            student.setSampleTimeStamp(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(reader.getValue()));
        }
        catch (ParseException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        reader.moveUp();
        reader.moveDown();
        student.setSalary(new BigDecimal(reader.getValue()));

        return student;
    }

}
```

**StackTrace for reader.getAttribute(0)**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.util.xml.XMLEventStreamReader.getAttribute(XMLEventStreamReader.java:211)
    at org.springframework.util.xml.XMLEventStreamReader.getAttributeValue(XMLEventStreamReader.java:192)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.StaxReader.getAttribute(StaxReader.java:92)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.ReaderWrapper.getAttribute(ReaderWrapper.java:56)
    at com.example.demo.utility.StudentConverter.unmarshal(StudentConverter.java:33)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1230)
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.doUnmarshal(XStreamMarshaller.java:826)
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.unmarshalXmlStreamReader(XStreamMarshaller.java:786)
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.unmarshalXmlEventReader(XStreamMarshaller.java:777)
    at org.springframework.oxm.support.AbstractMarshaller.unmarshalStaxSource(AbstractMarshaller.java:411)
    at org.springframework.oxm.support.AbstractMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractMarshaller.java:354)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader.doRead(StaxEventItemReader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:92)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.SynchronizedItemStreamReader.read(SynchronizedItemStreamReader.java:55)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.SynchronizedItemStreamReader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$987ea09.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.SynchronizedItemStreamReader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$66d53b5e.read(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:94)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:161)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:119)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:113)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**[NOTE]:** I tried to debug using following properties:

`reader.getAttribute(0)` -- throws error

`reader.getAttribute("name")` -- return null

`reader.getAttributeCount()` -- always return 0

I am unsure why the reader.getAttributeCount() returns zero as there are 5 fields associated with each student entry.

All I want is to achieve more control on StudentConverter.unmarshal part and I want to fetch attribute values by their name or some identifier, not by their position in xml as position are dynamic and may change later.

Answer (score 1):

When you've got something like `<a b="...">...</a>`, from an XML perspective, `a` is an element an `b` is an attribute.

Your XML does not have any attribute. That's why you've got zero for `.getAttributeCount()` and an exception for `.getAttribute(0)`.

An usual way to achieve what you want is to use a tool like Jackson, and use the relevant configuration/annotation to match each field according to desires input and output. See [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization) for a basic explanation of how to handle it.